# Where are the Mafia sitting for "A Series of Unfortunate Accidents"?

Tags: achievements, a-hat-in-time

The "*A Series of Unfortunate Accidents*" achievement in a Hat in Time says "*Knock off all the sitting Mafia in Mafia Town!*"

I've seen a few Mafia sitting around town, but I haven't been able find all of them. I'm not even sure how many there are, as there isn't any in-game counter to keep track.

**Where can I find all the sitting Mafia in Mafia Town?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achievement guide courtesy of [Gameplay.tips](https://gameplay.tips/guides/1283-a-hat-in-time.html):

> ### [A Hat in Time: A Series of Unfortunate Accidents](https://gameplay.tips/guides/1283-a-hat-in-time.html)
>
> #### What to Do
>
> You have to kick 5 members of the Mafia in Mafia town off a cliff (the
>   place for these five are fixed).  The best act for this is The Golden Vault.
>
> #### Where to Find the Five Mafia
>
> - **Mafia Number 1**: is just under the big lighthouse, sitting on the ledge of the pier.
> - **Mafia Number 2**: is near the place where the homeless mafia live. You can also find a golden vault code there. It's right above the
>     start point of Welcome to Mafia town.
> - **Mafia Number 3**: is sitting on one of the red steel shores of the construction site.
> - **Mafia Number 4**: is on the right side of Mafia Number 3. He's sitting on a house with a blue roof.
> - **Mafia Number 5**: is sitting on a tall, circular building that can also be a lighthouse, I really don't know what it should represent.

If you follow the route shown below, this achievement can be unlocked in just under a minute.